# CSS on links (formatted as buttons) displaying differently in Safari

Tags: css, safari, hyperlink

I've styled some links to look like buttons using:

a:link, 
a:visited, 
a:hover, 
a:active

However I'm finding that the a:active styling isn't working in Safari (on PC or iPad).

I've noticed that the stackoverflow buttons (Questions, Tags, Users etc) work the same in both Explorer and Safari. Does anyone know what CSS code is being used to achieve this?

Comment: Please add a sample of your CSS. Consider a jsfiddle.net example to help us answer your questions as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to check the CSS, you might use browser tools to inspect your element. Just right-click an element and select 'Inspect element' (wording might be slightly off). This will certainly work in FireFox, Chrome and Safari (I suppose in the other modern browsers as well). These will show you an element's source code and what CSS is applied on it. You can also search for add-ons to give you more functionality.

To get back to your question. I personally can't see any special a:active styles here on StackOverflow when clicking and holding on a link. Are you sure you are not confusing a:active (the state a link is in when you click/hold it) with the styling of a link to the current page?

Comment: I guess so. My buttons are in an iframe. In Explorer/Firefox when I click on one of them the styling stays on a:active whilst another iframe displays some new content. But in Safari the a:active styling disapears as soon as the mouse click is released. Is there any way of making the a:active styling remain like in Explorer/Firefox?

Comment: What Safari is doing is actually correct. The a:active state is there when you click on a link or click and don't release the mouse button. After clicking a link, it will be set to visited and will display the styling set in _a:visited_ CSS. Please, like was requested, do provide relevant source code when you ask a question, since it's very hard to determine where your problem stems from otherwise.